# Can't write this note

Tags: lilypond, transcription

I've been strugging with lilypond writing this on 4/4 bass clef

[image: quarters and eights together]

I appreciate if you enlighten me

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I've two clefs I'm still not sure how to implement this. Trying to figure it out. Once done I'll will update the thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
<< { c4 } \\ { a8 e } >>
```

(with relative pitches)

Adding clef:

```
\relative c' {
  \clef bass
  << { c4 } \\ { a8 e } >>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a short passage that has two voices, you can use temporary voices:

```
\version "2.24.1"
{ \clef bass << { c'4 } \\ { a8[ e] } >> }
```

If your piece has many places that use two voices, you might want to instead use separate voices:

```
<<
  \new Voice { \voiceThree \voiceThreeMusic }
  \new Voice { \voiceFour \voiceFourMusic }
>>
```